# Syntax error on if-else Javascript statement

Tags: javascript

I'm fairly new to JavaScript so I don't quite understand why I am getting a syntax error on 'else'. Any advise?

```
<script language="javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#toggleButton').click(function() {
           if ($('#toggleSection').css("opacity") == 0); {  
                $('#toggleSection').fadeIn("slow");
           } 
           else {
                $('#toggleSection').fadeOut("slow");
           }
           return false;
      });
 });
 </script>
```

Comment: For basic syntax errors, just run your code through http://jslint.com/.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if ($('#toggleSection').css("opacity") == 0);
```

Remove that semicolon on the end..

Answer (score 2):

```
if ($('#toggleSection').css("opacity") == 0); {
```

Hi, I think your ; is wrong here. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

You have an extra `;` after the `if`

This is parsed as an `if` around an empty statement (which is useless), followed by an ordinary `{ ... }` block, followed by a dangling `else`.